# Need "connect by" type query with MySQL for pagination

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, hierarchical-data, connect-by

I've got a `submissions_comments` table with has parents and children and each child has a 1:1 relationship and each parnet has a 1:many relationship.

That is, all parents can have unlimited (1 level deep children) and all children can have only 1 parent.

My current query works fine, since it returns ALL comments for a particular submission, which I then can do my nested in the front-end of my application, however, when I introduce an offset for ajax pagination, I'm grabbing only the parents that are in the offset, and if they contain a child comment that isn't returned in that particular offset, my nesting won't work.

How can I modify my query to get me all relevant child comments using an offset (such as 0,15 15,30, etc.)

```
    SELECT parent.id,
      parent.deleted,
      parent.comment,
      parent.user_id,
      parent.created,
      parent.parent_id,
      s.user_id submissionUserId,
      u.username,
      u.photo AS userPhoto
    FROM submissions_comments AS parent
    LEFT JOIN users u ON parent.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN submissions_comments AS child ON child.parent_id = parent.id
    LEFT JOIN submissions s ON parent.submission_id = s.id
    WHERE parent.submission_id = ?
    AND parent.deleted = 0
    GROUP BY parent.id
    ORDER BY parent.created DESC,
    child.created
    LIMIT 0,15 // or offset that I pass in from my front-end application.
```

Here is a sqlfiddle with the data/tables:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/924c8

**Also here is an example of the data that is out of order (e.g. the comment with `id` = 5 should be in the second set of results (not the first)**

Using an offset of initially 0,15 (as that's how many default comments are displayed on the page):

```
+-----+---------+-----------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| id  | deleted | comment               | user_id | created             | parent_id | submissionUserId | username | userPhoto                            |
+-----+---------+-----------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| 21 |       0 | Replying to comment 5 |      2 | 2014-08-08 01:14:42 |       5 |               58 | bobcobb2     | 772187eabd2df8ce62a2f1d59f61eb21.jpg |
| 20 |       0 | .... comment 20       |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:31 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 19 |       0 | .... comment 19       |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:29 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 18 |       0 | .... comment 18       |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:26 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 17 |       0 | .... comment 17       |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:23 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 16 |       0 | .... comment 16       |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:18 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 15 |       0 | .... comment 15       |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:16 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 14 |       0 | .... comment 14       |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:13 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 13 |       0 | .... comment 13       |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:11 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 12 |       0 | .... comment 12       |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:06 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 11 |       0 | .... comment 11       |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:05 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 10 |       0 | .... comment 10       |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:04 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 9 |       0 | .... comment 9        |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:02 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 8 |       0 | .... comment 8        |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:13:00 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 7 |       0 | .... comment 7        |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:12:57 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
+-----+---------+-----------------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

And then passing in the offset 15,30 when you click on the "Load More Comments..." link on page to fetch (older) comments.

```
+-----+---------+----------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| id  | deleted | comment        | user_id | created             | parent_id | submissionUserId | username | userPhoto                            |
+-----+---------+----------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| 6 |       0 | .... comment 6 |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:12:54 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 5 |       0 | .... comment 5 |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:12:51 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 4 |       0 | .... comment 4 |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:12:50 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 3 |       0 | .... comment 3 |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:12:48 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 2 |       0 | .... comment 2 |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:12:47 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
| 1 |       0 | .... comment 1 |      1 | 2014-08-08 01:12:41 |      NULL |               58 | bobcobb    | 935dc24b4529374bc1efcb782411f50e.png |
+-----+---------+----------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by an offset. Also, in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is inappropriate, and potentially misleading (although, irritatingly, it can be faster than the correct form)

Comment: @Strawberry edited my original post to clarify. Essentially it's just what I'm retrieving each time (e.g. how many entries). Also, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I see, but it would be more useful to show us what you'd actually want the result to look like (You could use a smaller offset for illustrative purposes, 0-5,5-10 say)

Comment: @Strawberry added an example above.

Comment: It seems to me that you are asking several questions here. By offset, you mean that you want to return records 0-15 to the user. Then, when they click to view the next page of results, you want to return records 15-30. Is that correct? I am a little confused by the next part. You want to change the order that the data is returned. Why is the comment with id 21 out of order? Where should it go? There is no parent with id 330. Should the parent id affect the ordering?

Comment: @Jenn that's a mistake from trying to replicate data on my machine. I've updated it to reflect what it should actually reference (id=5). My main question still remains, which is how to get the properly nested comments when I do my offset. So on first page load, they see comments 0,15. They want to read more so they click "View more comments" which sends in the new offset of 15,30, and then 30,45 until all comments are shown. Comment with id=21 is on top, because that's the order it was replied to, but because I initially fetched the comments with the offset 0,15 it shows up first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the issue is that one of the comments is returned out of order. Currently, your query is ordering all of the comments by their created date in descending order. This is generally correct, except in the case when one comment is a reply to another one. Then, the "child" comment needs to be returned at the same time as the parent comment. Here is a query that will achieve this ordering.

```
SELECT parent.id,
  parent.deleted,
  parent.comment,
  parent.user_id,
  parent.created,
  parent.parent_id,
  s.id as sid,
  s.user_id submissionUserId,
  u.username,
  u.photo AS userPhoto
FROM submissions_comments AS parent
LEFT JOIN users u ON parent.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN submissions s ON parent.submission_id = s.id
WHERE parent.submission_id = ?
AND parent.deleted = 0
GROUP BY parent.id
ORDER BY Case when parent.parent_id is null Then
          parent.created
         Else (Select p.created
               From submissions_comments p
               Where p.id = parent.parent_id) End DESC,
parent.id
LIMIT 15,30
```

The changes to your original query are the following:

- 1) The left join to the submissions_comments table has been removed. I
  removed this join because the table was only used in the order by. I
  used the same table in the order by clause, but the less self-joins,
  the better.
- 2) The order by now includes a case statement.

The order by needs to have a case statement because we need to completely change how the results are ordered if the record has a parent_id. The case statement will return the created date if the parent_id is null. If the parent_id is not null, the case statement will return the parent's created date. This will cause the child comment to be sorted right next to the parent comment.

Then, I ordered by the id so that the parent id would come first. This may not be what you want, you could order by parent.created desc instead so that all the child comments are returned before the parent comment. [Here is what it looks like, using the sql fiddle you provided.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/924c8/42)

Example Results (not all columns included):

> ```
> |id|deleted|user_id| created             | parent_id |submissionUserId| username |
> +-----+---------+----------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
> | 6|     0 |     1 | 2014-08-08 01:12:54 |      NULL |             58 | bobcobb |
> | 5|     0 |     1 | 2014-08-08 01:12:51 |      NULL |             58 | bobcobb |
> |21|     0 |     2 | 2014-08-08 01:14:42 |         5 |             58 | bobcobb2|
> | 4|     0 |     1 | 2014-08-08 01:12:50 |      NULL |             58 | bobcobb |
> | 3|     0 |     1 | 2014-08-08 01:12:48 |      NULL |             58 | bobcobb |
> ```

The only issue with this query is that the limit is going to supersede everything else. If a parent is listed as row 15 and the child is row 16, these results will NOT be returned together. The limit will stop at row 15.

The only other thing I would like to mention is that mysql does not allow you to pass a parameter in to the `LIMIT` clause. You may need to rethink this portion of your query if you are planning on passing the range that should be returned as a parameter. One possible solution is to create a temporary table and assign temp ids (based on the ordering of the results) and then only return the results that have the temp id between the range that you are looking for.

Comment: The offset is being passed in as a parameter that I'm just interpolating it depending on which page it's on (I keep track of it with my front-end through Javascript). Is there any way to circumvent that caveat you mentioned above re: the parent being id=15 and child being id=16 with an offset of 0,15? Any way to apply the offset ONLY to the parent?

Comment: @bob_cobb I believe that could be done with the use of temporary tables. The biggest issue I see is the potential for recursion in your data, which mysql does not handle very well. What if a child has a child and that child has a child? How should the data be ordered then? The only way to order this situation properly is by creating a separate stored procedure and calling that.

Comment: Thanks, Jenn. I'll look into that. As for recursive with this table, it's only 1 level deep (and all children would be ordered by created date DESC), so I don't think it'd be a huge issue.

Comment: My suggestion for the parents and children to always be returned together is to create a temporary table with a column 'countId' or something similar. When you encounter a parent, you assign a new countId (beginning with 1 and incrementing by 1). When you encounter a child, assign the same countId as the parent.

Let's assume your range is 0, 15. Select from the temporary table (instead of your submissions_comments) and specify that the count id must be greater than 0 and less than or equal to 15.